# I am having problems with <script> tag not working when it is clearly there in the html body in the browser console

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets, stringbuilder

I have a jsp file which has an "iframe" tag where my data is shown when user searches for a field. When user clicks search, my servlet gets userdata from the database and create html page using StringBuilder, and convert everything to string at the end and send it to the iframe tag to be displayed. It all works fine but my function inside the script tag is not being picked up by the browser when it is clearly there. I have tried putting my script function in the head and the body tag but it didn't work. Even I put a simple script function to print error it still gives me the same error. Here is how I am calling the function

```
htmlContent.append(String.format("<td><button type='button' onclick=\"sendRequest('%s')\">%s</button></td>",
```

Here is my script tag

```
htmlContent.append("<script>");
htmlContent.append("function sendRequest(RecorderID) {");
htmlContent.append("  var url = updateRecorderInfoServlet?RecorderID=' + RecorderID        
htmlContent.append("  console.log('Request URL:', url);");
htmlContent.append("     window.location.href = url;");
htmlContent.append("}");
htmlContent.append("</script>");
```

This is my jsp file

```
function submitForm() {
  // Get the form data
  var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('displayForm'));

 // Send a POST request using JavaScript Fetch API
 fetch('getRecorderInfoServlet', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
                body: formData.get('Recorder_ID')
            })
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
      // Update the iframe content
      document.getElementById('resultFrame').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = data;
  })
 .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}
```

...

```HTML
<header>    
  <a href="landingPageServlet" title="Home"><span>&#127968;</span></a>
  <h1>Search by User ID</h1>
</header>

...
<form id = "displayForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); submitForm();" >
  <label for="recorderId">Enter Recorder ID:</label>
  <input type="text" id="recorderId" name="Recorder_ID" required/>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<iframe id="resultFrame" name="resultFrame" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>


</body>
```

I am expecting to transfer the recorder id to to another servlet when user clicks on the recorder id in the table. I could've used dispatcher too but that doesn't allow me to use onClick. I want to transfer the user id only when user clicks on the tag. Manually putting the function in the browser console works perfectly fine.

Comment: Have you thought about creating a separate javascript file that you can edit without having to use so many quotes?

Comment: Yes, I tried creating a separate file but still get the "Function not defined error". My script and html code looks correct on the browser console in the network tab.

Comment: Have you checked in the browsers console that there isn't any errors?

Comment: The only error I get in the browser is that the function is not defined. Function is clearly there in the browser and everything else works fine if I manually put function in the console.